# R appending data to rows in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to run my data frame through a loop to execute a function on each row and update the columns `est`, `ll`, and `ul` with the results. My data frame is `onch`. The loop seems to be working except the results for `est`, `ll`, and `ul` are the same for each row (presumably the last iteration). Any thoughts would be appreciated!

```
for (i in 1:nrow(onch)) {
   row <- cbind(onch$c1, onch$c2, onch$c3)
   pr1 <- removal(row)
   a <- summary(pr1)
   onch$est <- a[1]
   b <- confint(pr1)
   onch$ll <- b[1]
   onch$ul <- b[2]
}
```

the data frame looks like this:

> onch

```
    site    date      c1   c2  c3   est   ll   ul
1   H1     7/11/12    6     2   1   NA     NA   NA
2   H2     7/15/12    12    4   0   NA     NA   NA
```

Thank you for the help! I still haven't solved the nrow copy issue, but this works:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(onch)) {

row <- cbind(onch$c1[i], onch$c2[i], onch$c3[i])
pr1<- removal(row)
a<- summary(pr1)
    onch$est[i] <- a[1]
b <- confint(pr1)
    onch$ll[i] <- b[1]
    onch$ul[i] <- b[1,2]
 }
```

Comment: how does onch looks like (e.g., names(onch)) ??

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data? For example using the principles explained at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155375/embedding-data-from-csv-file-in-line-of-code/155377#155377

Comment: The first problem I see is that you're not referencing anything with the `i`. So you're doing the same process invariant of row within the `for` loop, as there is no `i` inside the loop. Secondly, because R is assign-by-copy, you are needlessly creating `nrow(onch)` copies of a data frame when you can probably create just one. Finally, what is the `removal` function?

Comment: @Jochem For samples/examples, I prefer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the function `removal`?

Comment: The removal function is from the package FSA and is used to estimate fish abundance. Thank you for the comments. I will start by trying to incorporate the i into the loop, and will try to resolve the nrow(onch) copies issues.

Comment: For future reference, [documentation for `removal` at Rforge](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/FSA/removal.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your line `onch$ll <- b[1]` overwrites the *entire* column `ll` of `onch`. To only update a specific entry, use `onch$ll[ii] <- b[1]` for some index `ii`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to benefit from the question and answer given at: [How to optimize the following code with nested while-loop? Multicore an option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475039/how-to-optimize-the-following-code-with-nested-while-loop-multicore-an-option)

This question discusses many of the relevant principles and also indicates on how to optimise (vectorize) the code so in improves the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be making edits to this answer to explain it. In the meantime, give this a try. I don't have the FSA package (`install.packages` is squawking at me that it's not available for R 2.15.2), so I haven't tested it.

```
onch.removal <- lapply(1:nrow(onch),function(x) {
    pr1 <- removal(c(onch[x,"c1"],onch[x,"c2"],onch[x,"c3"]))
    return(list(est=summary(pr1)[[1]],ll=confint(pr1)[1],ul=confint(pr1)[2]))
})
onch <- data.frame(onch,onch.removal)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast solution using `data.table`, no need for loops.

```
library(data.table)
library(FSA)

setDT(onch)

onch[, v_est := summary(removal(c(c1, c2, c3)))[1] , by= site]
onch[, v_ll := confint(removal(c(c1, c2, c3)))[1] , by= site]
onch[, v_ul := confint(removal(c(c1, c2, c3)))[1,2] , by= site]
```