# constrained optimization of a complicated function

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I need to optimize the following to find the maximum value for `r1`:

```
ad = 0.95*M_D + 0.28*G_D + 0.43*S_D + 2.25*Q_D
as = 0.017*M_A + 0.0064*G_A + 0.0076*S_A + 0.034*Q_A
ccb = 0.0093*M_CC+ 0.0028*G_CC + 0.0042*S_CC + 0.0186*Q_CC
ccd = 0.0223*M_CD + 0.0056*G_CD + 0.0078*S_CD + 0.0446*Q_CD
apb = 1.28*M_P + 2.56*Q_P 
r1=(1+ccb*(1+ccd))*ad*as*100/(130-apb)
```

subject to the following constraints:

```
0 <= M_CD <= M_CC <= M_A <= M_D <= M_P <= 9
0 <= G_CD <= G_CC <= G_A <= G_D <= 9
0 <= S_CD <= S_CC <= S_A <= S_D <= 9
0 <= Q_CD <= Q_CC <= Q_A <= Q_D <= Q_P <= 3
```

The approach I've [tried before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890250/how-to-use-multicore-with-loops-in-r) doesn't work very well and I'm hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: [Task View "Optimization"](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html)

Comment: Is there an error here? `r1=(1+ccb*(1+ccd))*ad*ad*100/(130)` no `as` and no `apb`

Comment: as it stands the solution is the upper bound for all variables

Comment: Can you provide some background here?  I find it hard to believe there's a real-world problem with that many input variables and that many semi-independent constraints (especially since, as already noted, the maximum is obviously at max(all inputs) ).   PS @Roland, great reference page but sadly not useful to a naive OP.

Comment: Yeah sorry user it's `r1=(1+ccb*(1+ccd))*ad*as*100/(130-apb)` I made some this mistake when simplifying my problem

Comment: Again maximising ccb, ccd, ad, as, apb would seem to be the solution leading to the same solution upper bound for all variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem not with vectorization but with C. My program containing 14nested loops executes 100 to 1000 times faster with C than with R ! Which is sad because I didn't learn anything new from that and it prooves that R can be pretty useless on some problems but what can we do.

Answer (score 2):

Once the problem is stated correctly you maybe able to firstly map the parameters to lower and
upper bounds of [0,1]. You can then implement the inequalities inside your function and optimise using an algorithm which accepts basic lower and upper bound constraints. `nlminb` could be used but the vignette suggests the algorithm used may not be the best.

UPDATE:

With OP revised function

```
dumFun <- function(p){
    p[1] -> M_CD; p[2] -> M_CC; p[3] -> M_A; p[4] -> M_D; p[5] -> M_P;
    M_P <- 9*M_P; M_D <- M_P*M_D; M_A <- M_D*M_A; M_CC <- M_A*M_CC; M_CD <- M_CC*M_CD; 
    p[6] -> G_CD; p[7] -> G_CC; p[8] -> G_A; p[9] -> G_D;
    G_D <- 9*G_D; G_A <- G_D*G_A; G_CC <- G_A*G_CC; G_CD <- G_CC*G_CD; 
    p[10] -> S_CD; p[11] -> S_CC; p[12] -> S_A; p[13] -> S_D;
    S_D <- 9*S_D; S_A <- S_D*S_A; S_CC <- S_A*S_CC; S_CD <- S_CC*S_CD; 
    p[14] -> Q_CD; p[15] -> Q_CC; p[16] -> Q_A; p[17] -> Q_D; p[18] -> Q_P;
    Q_P <- 3*Q_P; Q_D <- Q_P*Q_D; Q_A <- Q_D*Q_A; Q_CC <- Q_A*Q_CC; Q_CD <- Q_CC*Q_CD; 

    ad = 0.95*M_D + 0.28*G_D + 0.43*S_D + 2.25*Q_D
    as = 0.017*M_A + 0.0064*G_A + 0.0076*S_A + 0.034*Q_A
    ccb = 0.0093*M_CC+ 0.0028*G_CC + 0.0042*S_CC + 0.0186*Q_CC
    ccd = 0.0223*M_CD + 0.0056*G_CD + 0.0078*S_CD + 0.0446*Q_CD
    apb = 1.28*M_P + 2.56*Q_P 
    r1=(1+ccb*(1+ccd))*ad*as*100/(130-apb)
    -r1
}
require(minqa)
p <- rep(.1, 18)
bobyqa(p, dumFun, lower = rep(0, length(p)), upper = rep(1, length(p)))
parameter estimates: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
objective: -9.65605526502482 
number of function evaluations: 97 
>
```

Comment: I think I understand what bobyqa does but I don't understand how you do to make constraints function of other variables. What do you mean by mapping parameters to [0,1] and why are you linking paramaters by multiplying them in dumfun function ?

Comment: for example if `0 < x,y,z < 1` and redefine `y1 = x*y` and z1 = y*z then `0 < z1 < y1 < x < 1`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand, the goal is to get the value of paramaters which must be integers from 0 to 9.

Comment: The fact that they are integers is rather important and something you failed to mention.

Comment: sorry I mentionned it on my previous posts. On this thread too but a moredator suppressed this information.